# json -- shell script execution in json

Tags: json, shell

I already have a working json scrip in which i am using shell script, i am trying to pass arguments to that shell script, tryed few options but getting syntax error. please advice how to pass arguments to following json.

```
"Fn::Base64": {
        "Fn::Join": ["", ["#!/bin/bash\n",
                "cd /tmp\n",
                "curl -kO https://example_git_url/script.sh\n",
                "chmod 755 userdata.sh\n",
                "/tmp/script.sh\n"
        ]]
```

Comment: That looks like...maybe some sort of cloudformation template?  There is no such thing as a "JSON script" in general, but if you tell us more about what you're trying to do we might be able to help out.

Comment: yes that right that is cloud formation template, the section i was pointing is user data in cloudformation. i am trying to pass arguments to shell script dynamic.. trying to figure out how to pass arguments to this shell script